# How to do Left Join in DB (Mongo)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am new to Mongo! Please help me **how to do left join in Mongo**

Sql Statement :

```
Select * from TableA left Join TableB 
on (TableA.col1 = TableB.col1 AND TableB.col2 = "ABC")
```

Please provide me the equivalent Mongo Query!!!

Thanks In Advance !

Comment: [MongoDB tells you how to join](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/joins-and-other-aggregation-enhancements-coming-in-mongodb-3-2-part-1-of-3-introduction) and you can see how to chain in this [duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813854/how-to-join-multiple-collections-with-lookup-mongodb)

Comment: @Raghaven was the answer helpful? Feel free to upvote&accept.

Answer (score 8):

As of Mongo 3.2, you can do the equivalent to a left outer join with the new $lookup operator added to the aggregation pipeline: https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup

Your query would become something like this:

```
db.TableB.aggregate([
{
  $match:{col2:"ABC"}
},
{
   $lookup:
   {
       from: "TableA",
       localField: "col1",
       foreignField: "col1",
       as: "aliasForTable1Collection"
   }
}
])
```