# nodejs/mongodb - Aggregate items by substring

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two related collections that contain documents as follows:

```json
/* heroes */
{ id: "HID_1", name: "A" }
{ id: "HID_2", name: "B" }
```

```json
/* weapons */
{ name: "WHID_1", weapon: "Sword" }
{ name: "WHID_2", weapon: "Lance" }
```

How can I aggregate them so I get a single document where I know "A" uses a Sword and "B" uses a Lance? I can't directly *join* them by `id` and `name` because their value isn't exactly the same, but Weapon has a `W`-prefix on it.

I made some attempts with `$substr` but no success so far.

```js
db.heroes.aggegate( [
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'weapons',
      let: { heroId: '$id' },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [ '$$heroId', { $substr: [ '$name', 1, -1 ] } ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: 'weapon'
    }
  }
] )
```

For reference, I also tried just hard-coding an ID with `{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ '$$heroId', 'HID_1' ] } } }` and it didn't work. I could just rename all `WHID` to `HID`, but I am curious about whether it is possible or not.

Comment: I dont see any problem you are facing https://mongoplayground.net/p/-aZcXbidTzT

Comment: It was a silly mistake of mine while copying the query, thank you for pointing it out. 

Answer (score 0):

Use $project to append the "W" to the heroID and then do a regular lookup like described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46969468

Answer (score 0):

I am laughing so hard right now, the query I posted is not the same I have in my code, and apparently I fixed it without knowing while I was copying it into the question. My `let` was wrong and defined `weapons.name` instead of `heroes.id`.

For anyone having a similar issue, the `aggregate` in the original post works as it should. I didn't notice it until @varman pointed it out, so thank you! And sorry for the silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
db.heroes.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      name: 1,
      newID: {
        $concat: [
          "W",
          "$_id"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "weapons",
      localField: "newID",
      foreignField: "name",
      "as": "data"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$data",
          "$$ROOT"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: 0,
      newID: 0
    }
  }
])
```

or

```
db.heroes.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "weapons",
      let: {
        heroId: "$id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$heroId",
                {
                  $substr: [
                    "$name",
                    1,
                    -1
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "data"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$data",
          "$$ROOT"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: 0
    }
  }
])
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "HID_1",
    "name": "A",
    "weapon": "Sword"
  },
  {
    "_id": "HID_2",
    "name": "B",
    "weapon": "Lance"
  }
]
```

[Mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/17mGhO7BXeA)