# MongoDB get documents from a collection not in other collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to get the documents from a collection where aren't in other collection (the common NOT IN clause in SQL).

If I run the next query:

```
db.Companies_Movies.aggregate([
    {
        $project: 
        {
            "CompanyList.Movies.Code" : 1
        }
    },
    {
        $match: 
        {
             "CompanyList.CodeCompany": "23"
        }
    },
    {   
        $lookup:    
        {
            from: "Movies",
            localField: "CompanyList.Movies.Code",
            foreignField: "Movie.Code",
            as: "matched_docs"
        }
    }
]);
```

This query shows the movies includes in CompanyList.Movies.Code and in Movie.Code. Good.
But I just have the rest of movies includes in CompanyList.Movies whose codes aren't included in Movie.Code.

As Nikos Tsagkas said in [Get "data from collection b not in collection a" in a MongoDB shell query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772936/get-data-from-collection-b-not-in-collection-a-in-a-mongodb-shell-query/) it should be sufficient to include the following sentence:

```
    {
        $match: { "matched_docs": { $eq: [] } }
    }
```

But when I run my final code, it doesn't returns anything:

```
    db.Companies_Movies.aggregate([
    {
        $project: 
        {
            "CompanyList.Movies.Code" : 1
        }
    },
    {
        $match: 
        {
            "CompanyList.CodeCompany": "23"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:    
        {
            from: "Movies",
            localField: "CompanyList.Movies.Code",
            foreignField: "Movie.Code",
            as: "matched_docs"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { "matched_docs": { $eq: [] } }
    }
    ]);
```

There are 59 documents that are not returned by this code.

---

This is my pipeline I've created in MongoDB Compass after Tom's changes and it still doesn't work:

```
[{
    $match: 
     {
        'CompanyList.CodeCompany': '23'
     }
     },
     {
          $lookup: 
          {
               from: 'Movies',
               localField: 'CompanyList.Movies.Code',
               foreignField: 'Movie.Code',
               as: 'docs'
          }
     }, 
     {
          $project: 
          {
               'CompanyList.Movies.Code': 1,
               'CompanyList.CodeCompany': 1
          }
     }, 
     {
          $match: 
          {
               docs:{  $eq: [] }
          }
    }]
```

If I delete the $project, it not works either.

---

Sample Data (reduced)

Companies_Movies collection:

```
{
_id:ObjectId("61bf47b974641866e1244e65"),
"CompanyList": {
    "CodeCompany": "23",
    "NameCompany": "Company Name Entertainment",
    "Movies": [{
        "Code": "123",
        "Name": "Title 1",
        "Order": 1,
        "UserDescription": null
    }, {
        "Code": "124",
        "Name": "Title 2",
        "Order": 2,
        "UserDescription": null
    }, {
        "Code": "125",
        "Name": "Title 3",
        "Order": 3,
        "UserDescription": null
    }],
    "DateInserted": {
        "$date": "2021-12-13T17:30:06.824Z"
    }
  }
}
```

Movies collection:

```
[{
_id:ObjectId("61bf57bc9d1f93b7ae5fa785"),
"Movie": {
    "Code": "123",
    "OriginalTitle": "Title 1",
    "Year": 2021
 },
_id:ObjectId("61bf57bc9d1f93b7ae5fa786"),
"Movie": {
    "Code": "124",
    "OriginalTitle": "Title 2",
    "Year": 2021
 },
_id:ObjectId("61bf57bc9d1f93b7ae5fa787"),
"Movie": {
    "Code": "125",
    "OriginalTitle": "Title 3",
    "Year": 2021
 },
_id:ObjectId("61bf57bc9d1f93b7ae5fa788"),
"Movie": {
    "Code": "126",
    "OriginalTitle": "Title 4",
    "Year": 2021
 }
}]
```

Anyone know what might be happening?

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply caused by your `$project` stage, after you run:

```
{
  $project: {
    "CompanyList.Movies.Code" : 1
  }
},
```

You're data will look like this:

```
{
   CompanyList: [
       {
          Movies: { code: "123", ... other fields } 
       }
   ]
}
```

Now you're trying to match `"CompanyList.CodeCompany": "23"`, but the field `CodeCompany` simply does not exist anymore as you did not provide it in the project stage.

So just change you're projection stage to include fields you will use in later stages:

```
{
  $project: {
    "CompanyList.Movies.Code" : 1,
    "CompanyList.CodeCompany": 1
  }
},
```

Comment: Tom, your changes still don't work. Any other solution?

Comment: You need to provide sample data then for both collections, it's very hard to guess what other problems might exist.

Comment: Done, Tom. I copied the sample.

Comment: It's the same issues, `$project` "deletes" the fields that you are not specifying, so when you try to use them in a later stage to match it will not work. look at this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/ukvqOomyS7b

Comment: If I deleted the $project, the query returns all records. https://mongoplayground.net/p/FEqIzLI7ZpV

Comment: there is just a mismatch in the collection name, https://mongoplayground.net/p/KN6d9lp_Zi9. it's working fine

Comment: Sorry, but it isn't working fine. The result is "no document found" and it should return two documents (codes: 124 and 125)

Comment: those are nested movies and not "documents", if you want those all you're missing is an `$unwind` before the lookup https://mongoplayground.net/p/Sff1nslGH_o

Comment: Eureka! Thanks, Tom.

Comment: Tom, Is it possible to return an only string array with the movie codes?

Comment: Not quite, the closest you can get is something like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/mFH0FwIs2NS

  the aggregation framework always returns an array of documents (objects)

Comment: Tom, Could you help me in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70776518/aggregation-between-a-mongodb-collection-and-an-external-array/70778067 ?