# Aggregation between a MongoDB collection and an external array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm looking for a method for join a collection and a external array of strings (with codes), that returns another string array with all codes of first array that aren't included in the collection.

The collection sample:

```
[{
    _id:ObjectId("61bf57bc9d1f93b7ae5fa785"),
    "Movie": {
        "Code": "123",
        "OriginalTitle": "Title 1",
        "Year": 2021
     }},{
    _id:ObjectId("61bf57bc9d1f93b7ae5fa786"),
    "Movie": {
        "Code": "124",
        "OriginalTitle": "Title 2",
        "Year": 2021
     }},{
    _id:ObjectId("61bf57bc9d1f93b7ae5fa787"),
    "Movie": {
        "Code": "125",
        "OriginalTitle": "Title 3",
        "Year": 2021
     }},{
    _id:ObjectId("61bf57bc9d1f93b7ae5fa788"),
    "Movie": {
        "Code": "126",
        "OriginalTitle": "Title 4",
        "Year": 2021
     }
 }]
```

the external array:

```
const codes = ["125", "127", "128", "129"];
```

the aggregation must compare "Movie.Code" with the array and returns another array with the next values:

```
returnCodes = ["127", "128", "129"];
```

How can I make it?

Comment: What do you mean by "array with the next values"?

Comment: Not clear to me what you mean by "the next value". Anyway, in [Aggregation Pipeline Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) you can use external variables the same way like field names, e.g. `{ $filter: { input: codes, cond: { $in: ["$$this", "$Movie.code"] } } }`

Comment: In the example, "127", "128" & "129" are the values that not are in the array of the collection (Movie.Code). If you see the sample collection, Movie.Code have four values ("123", "124", "125" & "126"). The only value include in the collection and in the external array is "125", due to, the return array (returnCodes in the example) must contains the other values ("127", "128" & "129")

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([  
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      Code: { $push: "$Movie.Code" }
    }   
  },   
  {
    $project: {
      returnCodes: {
        $filter: {
          input: codes ,
          cond: { $not: { $in: [ "$$this", "$Code" ] } }
        }
      }
    }   
  } 
]).toArray().shift().returnCodes
```

Of course, you could do it also in Javascript:

```
const codes = ["125", "127", "128", "129"];
const coll = db.collection.find({}, { Code: "$Movie.Code" }).toArray().map(x => x.Code);

returnCodes = codes.filter(x => !coll.includes(x));
```

Comment: Tested here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yt1GBF6GVu_

Comment: Is it possible to do this in other way (without group)? $group is too much hard for a collectión with +200000 documents.

Comment: I don't think so, because your collection has 4 documents (in your example) but as result you want one array with 3 elements. So, at some point there must be a $group.

Comment: See my update. Maybe add `{ $match: { "Movie.Code": { $nin: codes } } }` as first stage which may reduce the amount of documents significantly.

Comment: Your last method returns in const coll all $Movie.Code from the collection. +200000 codes (millions in the furure) and then compare if const codes are include in that. I think it's cheaper find in database one by one if all the codes in the first const are in the collection. The latter is what i'm doing now.  I think your first solution is closer to solving the problem, as long as the grouping can be removed and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Of course, if you don't like to `$group` then you could also loop over the documents `db.collection.find({}, { Code: "$Movie.Code" }).forEach( doc => ...)` but certainly this will be even slower.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241254/discussion-between-julioc-and-wernfried-domscheit).